# Does Microsoft SQL Server have something similar to 'sqlite:///:memory:'?

Tags: sql-server, python, virtual-memory, sqlite

Python 2.7
SQLAlchemy
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.50.2500.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    10.50.2500.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Operating System                                            6.1.7601

I'm making a reporting tool for MS-SQL Server and because of MSSQL's proprietary data types, I can't use a memory resident SQLite database.

Does MSSQL offer some similar memory-based location where I can make temporary tables?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? That is, given a small enough data set and lack of memory pressure on the instance/server, SQL Server will serve the data from memory.

Comment: The tool is accessing the data remotely, across a painfully slow connection. My hope was to load the table data once, into a memory resident table on the local reporting computer, and then just access the data from there. Currently every query (of even one row) takes about a second. Whereas loading the entire table data takes about 30 seconds.